# regex_token_iterator *it++ bug?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

for following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<regex>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    regex reg("/");
    string s = "Split/Values/Separated/By/Slashes";
    sregex_token_iterator it{std::begin(s), std::end(s), reg, -1};
    sregex_token_iterator end;

    while(it != end)
    {
        cout << *it++ << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

should output:

```
Split
Values
Separated
By
Slashes
```

but it outputs this:

```
Values
Separated
By

Slashes
```

the main code may be problem is `*it++`, if I write `cout << *it << endl;++it;`,it work right.

when I change the stand c++11 regex to boost-regex, `*it++` also work right.

I have check the head of regex, I think the `operator++(int)` function has no problem.

my clang version is

```
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn) 
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Is there anyone have such problem?

Is there a bug in clang?

Comment: Works on Visual Studio 13.

Comment: Are you using libc++ (clang's standard library implementation) or libstdc++ (GCC's standard library implementation)?

Comment: yes, clang 5 use libc++ as default. regex seems not implement in libstdc++

Comment: @user2763477: It is from GCC 4.9

Comment: try `*(it++)` does this change anything? I don't think it should,  curious anyway.

Comment: @PolyMesh unfortunatly, the outputs did't change.

Comment: It's not the regex. I changed the regex and still got a similarly weird output. And it was instantly fixed by using `cout << *it << endl;++it;`, but idk why it doesnt work this way

Comment: Thanks for the bug report. This has been fixed in top-of-tree libc++. Just for the record, there was no problem in the `operator++(int)`, but the copy constructor and assignment operator were not working correctly, so when you copied a `regex_token_iterator`, it sometimes shared data with what it was copied from.

Answer (score 3):

I found that it's a libc++ implementation bug.

Go to regex, insert the following two lines

```
    regex_token_iterator operator++(int)
    {
        regex_token_iterator __t(*this);
std::cout << "test---" << *__t << "---test" << endl;
        ++(*this);
std::cout << "test---" << *__t << "---test" << endl;
        return __t;
    }
```

you find that the value of *__t changed after ++(*this) !

Further dig into you will find that,

*__t is actually implemented by returning internal value_type pointer _*result*, while _*result* actually points to &_*position*->prefix(), which is the address of match_results' _*prefix* object, the address of this object never changed, but the content of it changed.